# Displaying hierarchical data in TreeView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I've got the following class... my `ViewModel` has a property `IEnumerable<ApplicationDetection> ApplicationDetections` and I'm trying to display it in a `TreeView` with the XAML below.

```
public class ApplicationDetection
{
    public ApplicationDetection(string name, IEnumerable<DeploymentTypeDetection> detectionMethods)
    {
        Name = name;
        DetectionMethods = detectionMethods;
    }
    
    public string Name { get; }

    public bool Detected => DetectionMethods.Any(x => x.Detected);

    public IEnumerable<DeploymentTypeDetection> DetectionMethods { get; }
}

public class DeploymentTypeDetection
{
    public DeploymentTypeDetection(string name, Condition condition)
    {
        Name = name;
        Condition = condition;
    }

    public string Name { get; }

    public bool Detected => Condition.Detected;

    public Condition Condition { get; }
}

public class Condition
{
    public Condition(string name, bool detected, IEnumerable<Condition> conditions)
    {
        Name = name;
        Detected = detected;
        Conditions = conditions;
    }
    
    public string Name { get; }

    public bool Detected { get; }

    public IEnumerable<Condition> Conditions { get; }
}
```

```
<Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding ApplicationDetections}">
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type detectors:ApplicationDetection}" ItemsSource="{Binding DetectionMethods}">
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type detectors:DeploymentTypeDetection}" ItemsSource="{Binding Condition}">
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type detectors:Condition}" ItemsSource="{Binding Conditions}">
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

The problem I have is... I can see the `ApplicationDetection.Name` (1st tier) and `DeploymentTypeDetection.Name` (2nd tier) but then I can't see anything below that, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: *what am I doing wrong?* you are binding ItemSource to something which is not a collection?

Comment: `DeploymentTypeDetection.Condition` needs to be an enumerable type, even if it only ever has one item.

Comment: @Peregrine That works. Make it answer I'll mark it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`DeploymentTypeDetection.Condition` needs to be an enumerable type, even if it has only one item.

e.g.

```
public IEnumerable<Condition> ConditionEnumerable => new [] { Condition }
```

and then bind to `ConditionEmumerable` for the `ItemsSource` in the data template for `DeploymentTypeDetection`.